# Extension method for string array and params

Tags: c#, extension-methods, parameters

How can I get both these two methods to compile?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(params string[] args)
{ // do something }
public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(this string[] args)
{ // do something }
```

I get this compile error:

```
Type 'Extensions' already defines a member called 'DoSomething' with the same parameter types Extensions.cs
```

So that I can do this:

```
new string[] { "", "" }.DoSomething();
Extensions.DoSomething("", "");
```

Without the params method, I have to do this:

```
Extensions.DoSomething(new string[] { "", "" });
```

**Update:** Based on the answer by [O. R. Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430156/o-r-mapper)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(string arg, params string[] args)
{
    // args null check is not required
    string[] argscopy = new string[args.Length + 1];
    argscopy[0] = arg;
    Array.Copy(args, 0, argscopy, 1, args.Length);
    return argscopy.DoSomething();
}
```

**Update:** I like [HugoRune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145999/hugorune)'s answer now.

Comment: Both `this` and `params` in the methods are basically syntactic sugar for the call site, and do not matter in the method definition itself, so from the viewpoint of the compiler, they are one and the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer:

Another option is to just put both methods in different classes. Since you never us the class name when calling the extension method (the one with the `this` parameter), the extension method can be in any public static class in the same namespace, without any noticeable difference.

```
// contains static methods to help with strings
public static class StringTools
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(params string[] args)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

// contains only extension methods
public static class StringToolsExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(this string[] args)
    {
        return StringTools.DoSomething(args);
    }
}
```

This way you avoid copying the string array, you do not need an additional overload with no arguments, and I would say it looks cleaner. I would always separate extension methods and other static methods to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 12):

You can add an additional parameter to the `params` version:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(string firstArg, params string[] moreArgs)
```

That should be sufficient for the compiler to distinguish it from the `string[]` extension method.

As suggested by user [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks), an additional overload without any arguments should be provided in this case, if the situation with an empty `params` array needs to be supported:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething()
```

Comment: As well as a parameter-less version.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can give one of the two methods a different name.  i.e. `DoSomething2`
2. You can just use one method.  It's the same method with the same parameter list; clearly they're doing the same thing (since you didn't give them different names as per #1).  Just combine them.
3. You can change the parameter list of one of the methods.  i.e. (this string[] args, object unusedParameter)